# Can't get UILabels to appear on UIViews created dynammically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

Trying to do something fairly simple. I'm creating a row of rectangles that are placed in a horizontally scrolling `UIScrollView`. The rectangles lay out perfectly. However, each rectangle has a `UILabel` placed on it. Only the first label is displayed. None of the others are. The red rectangles here are the basic `CGRect`s. The yellow is for me to debug whether the label is drawing correctly. As you can easily see, only the first label is displayed:

[image]

```
self.dayButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:21];

CGFloat buttonSpacing = 2.0f;
CGFloat buttonWidth = 50.0f;
CGFloat buttonHeight = self.contentView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat startX = self.contentView.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat thisX = startX;

for (int i=0; i<21; i++) {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(thisX, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    UIView *thisButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    // set up a label for each view
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:DEFAULT_FONT size:14];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DAY %d", i+1]];
    [labelsArray addObject:label];

    [thisButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    // now add these elements
    [thisButton addSubview:label];
    [thisButton bringSubviewToFront:label];
    [self.contentView addSubview:thisButton];
    [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:thisButton];
    [self.dayButtonsArray addObject:thisButton];

    CGRect contentSize = self.contentView.frame;
    contentSize.size.width = ((i+1) * buttonWidth) + (i * buttonSpacing);
    self.contentView.frame = contentSize;

    thisX += buttonWidth + buttonSpacing;
}
```

Comment: I think you can set `contentSize.size.width` once - after the loop, rather than setting it on each iteration.

Comment: Agreed, except that the value of the int is local to the loop. Easy solution, either way.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `frame` for both the UIView and UILabel.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(thisX, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
UIView *thisButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

// set up a label for each view
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; <-- this frame should have an origin.x of 0.0
```

The x origin for `label` should be adjusted with reference from `thisButton` since you are adding it as its subview.

Comment: Good idea. I tried `UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:thisButton.frame];` but same result. If I make the label a subview of the contentView, then it works, but I also have a tap gesture recognizer that I am afraid might not work. Very strange.

Comment: @usr55410 You are still setting the origin for UILabel with the UIView's origin. Use this: `UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, thisButton.frame.size.width, thisButton.frame.size.height)];`

Answer (score 0):

Your `x origin` of the `UILabel` does not move in the loop. So that means you're creating all your `UILabel` on top of each other

Try this:

```
float buttonWidth = 50.0f;
float buttonHeight = 50.0f;


for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    //note that the width is multiplying the i
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonWidth*i, 20, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DAY %d", i+1]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: The value of the x origin moves by virtue of the frame getting redefined each time through. Not that I'm getting it to work or anything...